# Why passing a simple pointer in this simple example will not work

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Why modifying ptr has no effect
on vector?
I'm trying to change value through f function.

```
void f(int *ptr, int size, int value){
    ptr=(int* )malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(ptr!=NULL){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            *(ptr + i) = value;
        }

}

int main (void)
{
  int *vector = NULL;
  f(&vector, 3, 324);
    printf("%p\n", vector);

}
```

Comment: Please turn on and _read_ your compiler's warnings.

Comment: (it shouldn't work anyway...)warning: passing arg 1 of `f' from incompatible pointer type|

Comment: Yes, so go ahead and fix that.

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning the results of `malloc` to the parameter `ptr`, which is local.  You should be assigning it to what `ptr` **points to**.

```
void f(int **ptr, int size, int value)
{
  *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: `ptr` is a parameter to your function, so it is a local variable.

Comment: @PiotrWera: The formal parameter `ptr` is a distinct object in memory from the actual parameter `vector`, and is local to `f`; changes made to `ptr` in `f` won't be reflected in `vector`.  Instead of writing to `ptr`, you need write to what `ptr` *points to*, or `*ptr`.  You were most of the way there, but you had the type for `ptr` wrong in your function prototype (should have been `int **ptr`, as Matt has shown).

Comment: And on top of all that, he's only allocating space for a single int, then trying to put multiple ints there.